# Div class :hover not working properly in IE

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the link below using Internet Explorer

http://mojogobbles.com.sg/cupcake-menu/

It seems that when i try to hover over a declared div class, the `:hover` does not work properly, but in chrome it works perfectly. Any idea why?

CSS solutions only please!

Here is the CSS coding

```
#f12{
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 470px;
    top: 1090px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    float: left;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#f12:hover ~ #floater{
    background:url(images/flavours/f12.jpg);
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    opacity: 100;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}

#f13{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 550px;
    top: 460px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all;
    -moz-transition: 1s all;
    transition: 1s all;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
}

#f13:hover ~ #floater{
    background: url(images/flavours/f12.jpg);
    opacity: 100;
}

#floater{
    width: 320px;
    height:320px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 30%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Also I see you have #floater referenced as a child to two separate IDs (f12 and f13). Do you have an element with the id "floater" on the same page in multiple locations? That would be bad, since IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Hi all, i'm using IE 9 and also, #floater is a fixed positioning, and there is only one instance of this element in the page..

Comment: it seems that making the background: transparent; for #f12 and #f13 is making it unselectable, do you have any workarounds for that? I changed it to black and when I hover over it, the floater shows up

Comment: As a side note, you can massively increase your page speed by converting the menu from a .png (821kb) to an 80% compressed .jpg (221kb) with no noticeable loss in appearance. The same is also true for your homepage slideshow, and anywhere you have photos.

Answer (score 2):

You have two doctypes and the first one is wrong putting IE into quirks mode. Just delete both of them and use this one: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: oh god really? I only declared a doctype in header.php!

Comment: I changed it to only <!DOCTYPE html> and not even :hover doesn't work.. =(

Comment: You still show the incorrect doctype. Put the one I show you in there alone.

Comment: okay rob i changed it to <!DOCTYPE html> in the page template itself and it doesnt seem to work properly

Comment: oh yes it works now! thanks! but however the original problem is not solved, how i make it selectable?

Comment: You are using CSS transitions which only work in modern browsers and not IE.